# Extracting the first element from an String ArrayList delimited with commas

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList like

```
[A-,90,91,92 | B-, 80, 81| C,75 ]
```

How would I extract A-, B- and C from the ArrayList.

- | indicates the next element in the ArrayList

---

Would it be possible to split up the Grades into one ArrayList and the Numbers into another ArrayList?

Comment: your array list is in Char?

Comment: each element is just one long String

Comment: Does each element include square brackets as well?

Comment: Your question will be much clearer if you show your declaration of your array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do a loop {
  1. Take a string from your list.   
  2. Split this string with the String.split method using comma as separator.   
  3. Take the element at position 0 from the array returned by split.
}
```

Comment: using `indexOf` is not more efficient than using `split` ?

Answer (score 0):

We split the string, take the first element, and remove the let `[` by taking the substring starting at the second character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
  String current = myList.get(i);
  String grade = current.split(",")[0].substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop your collection and use `indexOf` for comma,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("A-,90,91,92");
        list.add("B-, 80, 81");
        int commaIndex =0;
        for(String s : list){
         commaIndex=s.indexOf(","); 
         System.out.println( s.substring(0,(commaIndex == -1)?0:commaIndex));
        }

    }
```